# How to convert a string "23,6,43,5,10" to a list [23,6,43,5,10]?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to manipulate some int numbers of a text file, but the format of the text was very confunsing so all i could do was put then in a string like `xs = "23,4,5,32,5"` but is very difficult to work on these since all elements are strings, `x[0] = "2"`i want to put than in a format i could work on like: `xs = [23,4,5,32,5]`  where `x[0]=23`

Not all of the elements in the strings are int so i could not convert all the elements into int,`type(",") = str` and then again i need to separate the numbers in pairs or not based on the commas

Comment: `list(map(int,xs.split(",")))`

Comment: I'm glad comments can't be downvoted: `myList = eval("[" + xs + "]")`

Comment: @Neftas aw, come on, at least [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) it!

Answer (score 1):

As [Pandraic Cunningham commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703957/how-to-convert-a-string-23-6-43-5-10-to-a-list-23-6-43-5-10#comment51346431_31703957) you can achieve that in one line using Python built-ins:

```
list(map(int, xs.split(',')))
```

First of all you split your string, using `','` as a separator by `xs.split(',')`. So you get `['23', '4', '5', '32', '5']`.

Then you need to convert all the string elements to `int`'s, which is done by doing `int(string_number)`, but you need to do that with all elements of your list. So you can do that using `map`.

As you may notice, the first argument is `int` and the second is the string list we obtained. What the `map` function does, it applies the `int()` on each of the elements of the list, by which generates a new list.

So:

```
>>> list(map(int, "23,4,5,32,5".split(',')))
[23, 4, 5, 32, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a list comprehension:

```
[int(num) for num in xs.split(",")]
```